# Set ID as input value on click of an element

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I click on my link it temporary pops up with the id number of that link.

**Question** How could I make it so if I click on a link then id would add that id to the input value where id is `input[id="language_id"]`

Code-preview [MY Codepen Example](http://codepen.io/riwakawebsitedesigns/pen/GJZzxp)

JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".language li a").click(function(event) {

    // Test make sure getting id
    alert(event.target.id);
  });
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <ul class="dropdown-menu language" role="menu">
    <li><a href="#" id="1">Test 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="2">Test 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="3">Test 3</a></li>
    <br/>
    <br/>
  </ul>
  <form action="" method="post" id="language-form">
    <input type="text" name="language" id="language_id" placeholder="Displays ID" value="" />
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: `Id` should be unique

Comment: yes as @Tushar mentioend you have duplicate id="language_id". Which is not good. Ids must be unique

Comment: Its only for testing the double input will be only having hidden

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have elements with the same ID; which is invalid HTML. Change one of them or use classes.

[**Element.id**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/id)

> It must be unique in a document

For your question use `this.id` with `val()`,

```
$('#language_id').val(this.id)   //or event.target.id
```

**[Updated Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RPadKK)**

```
$(".language li a").click(function() {
    $('#language_id').val(this.id)
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change the `id` of textbox by setting the id attribute of textbox.

```
$(".language li a").click(function(event) {
   document.getElementById('language_id').id =  event.target.id;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".language li a").click(function(event) {

// Test make sure getting id
//alert(event.target.id);
  $("#language_id").val(event.target.id);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".language li a").click(function(event) {

    $("#language_id").val(event.target.id);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

your element`id` shoud be unique

```
$(".language li a").click(function(event) {
    $("input[id=language_id]").val(event.target.id);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To add multiple ids to the control Please give a try to this:

`$(document).ready(function() {
     $(".language li a").click(function(event) {
       var str = $('#language_id').val() + "," + this.id;
       $('#language_id').val(str.replace(/^,?/,""));
     });
 });`